# PHP gives fatal error for curl extension in windows. curl_init undefined

Tags: php, apache, curl, wampserver

i have tried everything to load curl extension but it is not displayed in the loaded extension list.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suppose you did restart your Apache after installing the extension?

Comment: @Andy php_curl.dll also enabled in php.ini, extension=curl also uncommented both these lined uncommented

Comment: @Andy - i did not install, its already installed in my windows. still i download from curl website- and extracted the zip file to get the curl.exe file and placed the PATH environment variable according to the location of curl.exe file

Comment: I had an answer prepared about uncommenting in php.ini and then read your comment that it's already enabled. Please check wheter it's uncommented in the correct file that Wampserver uses - you might have more of them on the system (one for php-cli, another one for php on apache [which is probably source for the first screenshot], ...).

Comment: @PetrHejda i have found two files one of apache and other for php. i have added the php_curl.dll line in both files but still it ain't working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as I was using multiple versions of PHP so after deselecting the current version, selecting another version and then again selecting back the current version and then restarting the server made it work.

Comment: Then likely all you needed to do was `right click wampmanager icon->Refresh`

Answer (score 2):

In WAMPServer activating and deactivation extension for the WebServer (Apache) is simple

Use the WAMPServer menus, on the icon in the system tray (it may need to be takes out of the extension area to make sure it sits on the taskbar all the time.

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extensions
```

You should see a menu popout like this

[image]

Notice, the extension names all listed, if they have a Green Tick then they are activated, if not, they are not. To activate or deactivate the extension click the extensions name. Wait 10 second while WAMPServer restarts Apache automatically for you and there you go, Job Done.

**If you want to use PHP CLI**

The PHP CLI is controlled differently, there are actually 2 `php.ini` files. The one in the `wamp64\bin\php\php{version}` controls the PHP CLI.

You have to edit this one yourself, so edit `wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.16\php.ini` and make sure that

```
extension=curl
```

does not have a `#` comment in front of it

*Its a little odd that it is not already activated as WAMPServer comes, out of the box, with the curl extension pre-activated*